# Good simulation software for mobile devices

Tags: development-environment, mobile-phones

Can anyone recommend good simulation software for mobile devices?  I am most interested in Nokia smart phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right! The Nokia phones runs on Symbian Platform.

There are quite some variants out there, But [S60](http://www.s60.com/life) is better. UIQ is not doing that well lately.

Have a read at [**Developing with S60**](http://www.s60.com/life/thisiss60/S60forbusiness/developers)

You can download the SDK from [forum.nokia.com](http://www.forum.nokia.com/main/resources/tools_and_sdks/). So the Emulator comes with the Developer Kit. You can try to build and run the samples on Emulator to get first hand feeling.

Unfortunately Developing for Symbian is not walk-in-the-park.
You can get some developer feelings here:

- [Symbian OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685/symbian-os)

Alternatively you can look for Windows Mobile. Which has pretty easy learning curve if you have prior knowledge in any of the areas [Win32, or MFC or .NET C#]

[**Getting Started with Windows Mobile**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb264329.aspx)

or If you are comfortable with Java, check out [**J2ME**](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/). It has a wireless toolkit with decent emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for Emulator for Nokia phones? You can find those [here](http://www.forum.nokia.com/main/resources/tools_and_sdks/listings/)..

Otherwise explain clearly what kind of simulation software you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The Nokia S60 SDKs have an emulator which will run on the pc.

http://www.forum.nokia.com/main/resources/tools_and_sdks/

Symbian phones can be programmed in a variety of languages, not just Symbian C++. There's OpenC, Ruby, Py60 (Python), web programming and of course the various flavours of Java.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am showing my newb-ness with mobile development.  I am talking about emulation rather than simulation.

I am contemplating porting an application to a phone platform and like the look (and ubiquity in my market) of Nokia smart phone, which I think run Symbian.  What I would like to do is experiment by creating a development environment locally but I am a little lost and need some pointers to get started.

Answer (score 0):

A relevant shameless plug.

A recent book from Symbian Press is targeted at developers new to mobile development.

It guides you step by step through a 2 weeks learning curve and can greatly help porting efforts.

http://developer.symbian.com/quick

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, not all Nokia phones run Symbian. Only the Series 60 smart phones devices run Symbian, the lower end Series 40 devices run a proprietary OS. Your best bet is to use [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/index.php) to determine what the capabilities of each device are.

The nice thing about the Nokia S60 emulators is how well they are integrated with Eclipse and Netbeans. I am personally using Eclispe and the S60 emulator to develop a J2ME application and it was all quite straight forward to set up.